# How to clear out of memory using bitmap -- android

Tags: android, performance

I have various of images in my application, using drawable i importing those images. But whenever i tried high resolutions of images, i regularly getting

> 09-02 11:52:09.289: E/AndroidRuntime(29749):
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget 09-02
>   11:52:09.289: E/AndroidRuntime(29749):    at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 09-02
>   11:52:09.289: E/AndroidRuntime(29749):    at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)

For this particular issue i used following codes to clear the bitmap when i moves to next activity

```
 protected void onPause() {
          super.onPause();

          MemoryClearManager.unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.mainlayout));
          System.gc();
          Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
         }




public class MemoryClearManager {

    /**
     * @param view
     * Removes callback on all the background drawables
     * Removes child on every view group
     */
    public static void unbindDrawables(View view) {
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            try{
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Even i do this, i cant able to solve the memory issue. The same code i can able to run in some other device. Can anyone please guide me to solve this particular issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ur bitmap size is quite huge so u need to scale that

Comment: Thanks for replies, do you mean the resolution size or file size?

Comment: You can try to decode bitmap with small size

Comment: file size or rather good is to make thubnail of it

Comment: @HariRam try to generate a new bitmap object with new width and height and scaling..

Answer (score 0):

**Try this decoder**

*You can pass size that you want to display.*

```
public Bitmap decodeStream(InputStream is,int size) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null ,o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = size;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null ,o);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```